# Best way to serialize/deserialize .Net object<->JSON, containing Dictionary<Foo, dynamic>?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I try to serialize/deserialize the following class objects:

```
public class LiveDataFeedModuleConfiguration
{
    public Dictionary<VendorID, dynamic> LiveDataFeedAPIConfigurations { get; private set; }

    public LiveDataFeedModuleConfiguration(Dictionary<VendorID, dynamic> liveDataFeedAPIConfigurations)
    {
        this.LiveDataFeedAPIConfigurations = liveDataFeedAPIConfigurations;
    }

    public void AddElement(VendorID vendorId, dynamic liveDataFeedAPIConfiguration)
    {
        LiveDataFeedAPIConfigurations.Add(vendorId, liveDataFeedAPIConfiguration);
    }
}
```

I tried ServiceStack but when I deserialize the dynamic objects that are stored as dictionary values are empty. I tried Json.Net as well but I do not like that the dictionary, after deserialization, contains JObjects. I simply want to have an object of type `LiveDataFeedModuleConfiguration` returned that contains the `Dictionary<VendorID, dynamic>` where I can easily cast in .Net from dynamic tytpe to the **known** object type. Is there a way in Json.net to circumvent the JObject "clutter" and correctly deserialize into the types stored in the dictionary values? I used `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LiveDataFeedModuleConfiguration>(string jsonContent);`. But it deserializes into dictionary values of type jObject which is not desired.

Any solution that gets this working with json.net (given, I can get the correct serialization done in a generic deserialization method) or other library is welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: it doesnt look like your having very much success with this. you may need to create this functionality from scratch or avoid using a dictionary, and circumvent the issue completely. please post back here when you have a solution

Comment: @Idogorman, indeed I am convinced most all .Net JSON serializer libraries handle dynamics very poorly. I decided to serialize each POCO individually instead of storing them in a dynamic dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving away from storing dynamics in dictionaries for JSON serialization purposes. Most all libraries I mentioned are very unstable when it comes to handling dictionaries that contain dynamics.

Answer (score 0):

check this out. https://github.com/jsonfx/jsonfx

This works with dynamic

Comment: It does not seem to work as it does run into trouble deserializing into my VendorID enum. But thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you'd still consider going back to your original expression of intent in your code, as in your question:

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/39084/#Comment_39084

'Hope this helps,

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class? As far as I can tell you can write something like

```
var _object = JavaScriptSerializer.Deserializer<LiveDataFeedModuleConfiguration>(yourJSON);
```

and you will get your `LiveDataFeedModuleConfiguration` instance

Comment: I get my LiveDataFeedModuleConfiguration, that is not the problem. The problem is that I do not get the correct object types which I stored in the dictionary when I serialized in the first place.

Comment: JavaSriptSerializer can only handle dictionary keys of type string or object.